# How to compare attribute of a HTML Text box in jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I need to find whether a HTML text box is disabled or not in IF{} Statement using jquery..

I tried like this...

```
  $('[id$=txtpieceleny]').attr("disabled",true);

  if($('[id$=txtpieceleny]').attr("disabled") == "true") {
     alert("Hello");
  }
```

Kindly help me...

Comment: Instead of `== "true"` change to `== "disabled"`.

Comment: You are using ends with selector and might be getting more then one element, do you want to check single or all element being returned

Comment: Thank u all for ur answers..

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`.is(":disabled")`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to identify that,

```
if ($('[id$=txtpieceleny]').is(":disabled")) {
```

But since you are invoking this over a `collection` of elements the result would be an outcome of `OR` operation. That means if any one of the text box is disabled in that collection, the result would be true. And FYKI, please don't use `.attr()` for setting properties use `.prop()` instead.

And here is the reason [why we should not use .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can compare directly

Use attr it will return `string` type

```
if($('[id$=txtpieceleny]').attr("disabled")) {
    alert("Hello");
}
```

Or

```
if ($('[id$=txtpieceleny]').attr("disabled") == "disabled") {
   alert("Hello");
}
```

Use Prop it will return `true or false`

```
if ($('[id$=txtpieceleny]').prop("disabled")) {
   alert("Hello");
}
```

Comment: bala you are genius The OP asks one question but you give more than one answers. Really you genius

Comment: so i will give +1 for you

Answer (score 0):

Use `:disabled` selector in jquery to check

```
if ($('[id$=txtpieceleny]:disabled')){


}
```

or

```
if($('[id$=txtpieceleny]').attr("disabled")) {
     alert("Hello");
  }
```

Comment: then what will it retuns

Comment: @bala can you give me a sample fiddle

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy see the above sample